# CopyPagesTo copying Field dictionaries bug (with suggestion of fix) or only result of wrong PDF input file?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am dealing with a collection of PDF documents generated by some application. On many pages there are PDF Widgets annotations with some Javascript code enabling some sort of navigation among pages. I tried to merge two such documents with iText 7.1.14 (with `PdfDocument.CopyToPages` method) and noticed that in result file interactivity doesn't work any more. To locate the problem I tried to copy with `PdfDocument.CopyToPages` only one page of one document and result was similarly wrong.

After some analysis with RUPS i noticed potential cause related to /Kids array of /Parent field dictionary. ([See image of original document here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI3Uq.png)) I checked with RUPS similar entry in file produced with `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo` ([See image of copied document here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2AlR.png)) In that file /Kids array is empty which according to my understanding of PDF Reference 1.7 shouldn't be (it should point to kids of field parent).

I am not sure if such functionality of iText7 is a bug of iText or result of wrong pdf content of original file. Anyhow I tried to locate code in iText7 dealing with producing that output. I found `PdfPage.RebuildFormFieldParent` method which deals with copying /Parent dictionary.

```
        private void RebuildFormFieldParent(PdfDictionary field, PdfDictionary newField, PdfDocument toDocument) {
            if (newField.ContainsKey(PdfName.Parent)) {
                return;
            }
            PdfDictionary oldParent = field.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Parent);
            if (oldParent != null) {
                PdfDictionary newParent = oldParent.CopyTo(toDocument, JavaUtil.ArraysAsList(PdfName.P, PdfName.Kids, PdfName
                    .Parent), false);
                if (newParent.IsFlushed()) {
                    newParent = oldParent.CopyTo(toDocument, JavaUtil.ArraysAsList(PdfName.P, PdfName.Kids, PdfName.Parent), true
                        );
                }
                RebuildFormFieldParent(oldParent, newParent, toDocument);
      /**** ORIGINAL CODE BELOW *****/
                PdfArray kids = newParent.GetAsArray(PdfName.Kids);
                if (kids == null) {
                    newParent.Put(PdfName.Kids, new PdfArray());
                }
      /******************************/
                newField.Put(PdfName.Parent, newParent);
            }
        }
```

After some analysis I tried with the following change at the end of the method.

```
            private void MyRebuildFormFieldParent(PdfDictionary field, PdfDictionary newField, PdfDocument toDocument)
        {
            if (newField.ContainsKey(PdfName.Parent))
            {
                return;
            }
            PdfDictionary oldParent = field.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Parent);
            if (oldParent != null)
            {
                PdfDictionary newParent = oldParent.CopyTo(toDocument, JavaUtil.ArraysAsList(PdfName.P, PdfName.Kids, PdfName
                    .Parent), false);
                if (newParent.IsFlushed())
                {
                    newParent = oldParent.CopyTo(toDocument, JavaUtil.ArraysAsList(PdfName.P, PdfName.Kids, PdfName.Parent), true
                        );
                }
                RebuildFormFieldParent(oldParent, newParent, toDocument);
      /**** NEW CODE BELOW *****/
                PdfArray kids = (PdfArray)(oldParent.GetAsArray(PdfName.Kids).CopyTo(toDocument, true));
                if (kids == null)
                {
                    newParent.Put(PdfName.Kids, new PdfArray());
                }
                else
                {
                    newParent.Put(PdfName.Kids, kids);
                }
      /******************************/
                newField.Put(PdfName.Parent, newParent);
            }
```

After that change I generated copy of document with `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo`. RUPS shown [expected content of /Kids array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98xSD.png) and interactivity worked in copied document similarly as in original. I had to switch off `SmartCopy` mode (it thrown `SmartModePdfObjectsSerializer.SelfReferenceException` if enabled). For me this is somehow understandable, but could be the effect of wrong fix.

Could somebody verify if there is a bug in iText or iText works well but input file does not follow PDF reference? I am also not sure if (if it is a bug) my fix is appropriate or only works for my case.

Original file can be checked from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0yse7w68egd31o/OnePage.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: To rule out "result of wrong pdf content of original file" you need to provide the original file.

Comment: Thanks @Amedee for suggestion. I added [link to original file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0yse7w68egd31o/OnePage.pdf?dl=0) at the end of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer to my own question: **The problem was in input file and not in iText.**

Input file was incorrectly formed so that **there was no /AcroForm dictionary in pdf catalog**. When opening original file Adobe Acrobat Reader interpreted fields in each page so, that interactivity worked in spite of this irregularity of PDF file. Consequently I didn't suspect such a problem. After copying that bad formed PDF file with `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo`, field dictionaries were incorrectly formed (/Kids arrays were empty) and interactivity didn't work any more.

When I programatically added missing /AcroForm dictionary and its /Fields array pointing to root field dictionaries in original file PDF file and so made input file according to PDF reference specification, `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo` copied document properly and inteactivity of original file was properly transferred to copied document.

I used `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo` overload which used `copier` argument referencing instance of `PdfPageFormCopier`.

Actually, after some research I noticed that with such ill formed PDF file (without /AcroForm dictionary in spite of AcroForm fields in document) call of `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo` overload with `copier` argument referencing instance of `PdfPageFormCopier` produces exactly the same result as **if `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo` overload *without* `copier` argument would be called to copy *properly* formed input file**. That means that calling `CopyPagesTo` without proper `copier` argument when input file is having Acrofields produces output file which is not according to PDF Reference (it has field dictionaries with empty /Kids arrays).